# How to remote-access an iMac with the screen turned off?

Tags: networking, mac, vnc

I have an iMac (late 2011 edition) running Ubuntu Unity 22.10. It is in my departmental office, and I want to access/control it from my home computer (they are *not* connected to the same local network).

I tried using RealVNC, but the contents of the screen are visible on the physical monitor (and consequently, to other people in the office, while I am not in front of the iMac - which would be a bit weird).

Is there any way to turn of the physical screen while I access it through VNC (or any other protocol)?

If it were a regular desktop computer instead of an iMac, I could simply disconnect the display (so that the computer could be accessed by VNC while the display would remain turned off), but that is not an option here.